# Django Model Not Updating

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to count the amount of times a user visits a page:

models.py:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    view = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    visits = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

views.py

```
def daygaps(request,*a, **kw):

    request_counter = Request.objects.filter(
        user__username = request.user.username, view = 'daygaps')

    if request_counter:
        request_counter[0].visits += 1
        request_counter.update()

    else:
        Request.objects.create(
            user = request.user,
            visits = 1,
            view = 'daygaps')
```

When a new user visits the page for the first time, 'visits' gets set to = 1. Each subsequent visit should iterate the count. The "else" block works fine, however "visits" stays at 1 and does not change with each new request a user makes.

I've tried the ".save()" method, but that throws an error because "request_counter" is a queryset.

Comment: Did you try `request_counter[0].save()`?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Can you explain why?

Comment: You should update a specific instance of query, Not all the query. Your query returns a queryset. Like lists. try updating `request_counter[0]`

Comment: Psst, I can make it work with `update` =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

models.py

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    view = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    visits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def daygaps(request,*a, **kw):

    request_counter = Request.objects.get_or_create(
        user = request.user, view = 'daygaps')

    request_counter.visits += 1 # or =F('visits')+1 to avoid a race condition as suggested by Moses Koledoye
    request_counter.save()
```

OR

models.py

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    view = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    visits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

views.py

```
def daygaps(request,*a, **kw):

    updated_count = Request.objects\
        .filter(user = request.user, view = 'daygaps')\
        .update(visits=F('visits')+1)

    if not updated_count:
        Request.objects.create(user = request.user, view = 'daygaps')
```

which avoids race conditions too and has an added advantage of not having to retrieve the object.

In general, I guess the second one is better if the update is simple enough to be implemented with `F` expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `filter` and indexing the list returned by the QuerySet, you could simply use `.get` to return the object:

```
from django.db.models import F

def daygaps(request,*a, **kw):
    ...
    request_counter = Request.objects.get(
        user__username = request.user.username, view = 'daygaps')
    request_counter.visits = F('visits') + 1
    request_counter.save()
```

You can wrap the logic in a `try/except` to handle `DoesNotExist` exceptions.

The `F` expression helps you manage race conditions. Read more: [Updating attributes based on existing fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields)